# Socat on raspberry Pi for Serial over UDP

Tags: udp, raspberry-pi2, socat

I have a RPi connected to a Windows 8 machine through ethernet and I need to transfer data from the PC with udp to the RPi and out to one of its USB ports. I am using a program called SOCAT. I found this command on a help site, but it produces an error that basically says there are too many parameters:

```
socat STDIO:/dev/ttyS0,nonblock,raw,echo=0 UDP-LISTEN:1234
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command:

```
    socat /dev/ttyUSB0 UDP4-DATAGRAM:10.0.15.255:8888,broadcast
```

This will broadcast all the incoming information from the ttyUSB0 in UDP datagrams with destination port 8888 and also all the UDP datagrams that arrive to the port 8888 will be forwarded to the `/dev/ttyUSB0`